# c# process.waitforexit(int time)

Tags: c#, winforms, процесс

Поясните, пожалуйста, механизм останова процессов в приложении c# winforms.
В моем приложении имеется цикл, который запускает cmd на выполнение команды.
В зависимости от параметров запуска команда может отрабатывать разное время, посему надо давать время на ожидание завершения.

Пока сделал так:

```
            Process vote = new Process();
            vote.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd");
            vote.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            vote.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            vote.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            vote.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            vote.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            vote.OutputDataReceived += new     DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
            vote.Start();
            vote.StandardInput.WriteLine(vote_string);
            vote.BeginOutputReadLine();
            vote.WaitForExit(7000);
            vote.Close();
```

При этом замечаю в диспетчере задач, что иногда накапливается черезчур большое количество запущенных cmd, что забивает оперативку и приводит к просадке производительности.

Стал изучать msdn по теме останова процессов и все равно не пришел к пониманию, как в моем случае организовать освобождение ресурсов.

По сути вопросы следующие:

1. закрывается ли самостоятельно cmd в случае успешной отработки? вроде бы нет
2. как правильно использовать waitforexit? он ведь не предполагает под собой освобождения ресурсов, а лишь выдает, завершился процесс или нет. Видимо, надо писать if-блок, который, в случае, отрицательного ответа от waitforexit будет принудительно закрывать процесс, это так?
3. каким методом пользоваться для завершения процесса? про close() написано, что он высвобождает ресурсы. Процесс при этом завершается или нужно все-таки использовать kill() ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Нет.
2. WaitForExit ничего не делает с процессом. Она только ждет отведенное время пока процесс сам завершит работу.
3. Про способы закрыть процесс:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952635/what-are-the-differences-between-kill-process-and-close-process

Скорее всего вы даете командной строке команды запускать другие приложение. И проблема в том, что те приложения выполняются, а командные строки остаются. Если это так, то вместо создания процессов-командных-строк, вы можете запускать процессы с нужными командами

```
var proc = Process.Start("C:\myprog.exe /param");
proc.WaitForExit(7000);
```

В этом случае он будет ждать завершения команды, а не командной строки.

Либо, если вам необходимо запускать именно командые строки, то, чтобы понять, завершилась команда или нет, нужно анализировать вывод командной строки:

```
var result = vote.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

И по содержанию `result` делать вывод о завершении команды. Так же в этом случае хорошо бы переиспользовать существующую командную строку (или несколько), посылая в нее команды по очереди, а не создавать новый процесс каждый раз.

Comment: спасибо, поэкспериментирую.
У меня запускается cUrl, так что Ваше предложение очень уместно.